# constant expression require in java switch case (field is final and initialized)

Tags: java

```
public static final Integer SAMPLE = 100;

public static void doSomething(int errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode) {
        case SAMPLE:
            // ...
           break;
    }
}
```

I got constant expression required. if i change SAMPLE to int it will get fix. why ?

Answer (score 8):

The relevant parts of the language spec are in [JLS Sec 14.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> Every case label has a case constant, which is either a **constant expression** or the name of an enum constant.

This explains why you can't use an `Integer` value: it's not a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), since it is evaluated at runtime.

The fix is to change the case label to have a constant expression. To know what types are allowed, read on in the same section of the spec:

> - Every case constant associated with the switch statement must be assignment compatible with the type of the switch statement's Expression (§5.2).

and

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs.

Since you can't have a constant wrapped primitive type (`Character`, `Byte`, `Short` or `Integer`: they're all evaluated at runtime), this means that case labels can only be:

- `char`
- `byte`
- `short`
- `int`
- `String`
- An enum constant

The easiest option is to change your declaration of `SAMPLE` to:

```
public static final int SAMPLE = 100;
```

Note that 100 is in the guaranteed-cached range of `Integer.valueOf`, so there is no cost of declaring the value as a primitive: where you need a boxed value, a value is used from the cache.

Answer (score 4):

Switch can only work with some primitives (char, byte, short, int), enum values and Strings.

change it to;

```
public static final int SAMPLE = 100;
```

Comment: @AndyTurner that quote refers to the expression in the switch statement, but the OP is referring to the expression in the case label.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou you're right. It's this one that's relevant: "Every case label has a case constant, which is either a constant expression or the name of an enum constant.", plus a link to [what constitutes a constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Comment: @AndyTurner He is asking "Case label" not "switch" variable.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou actually, my original quote *was* relevant: "Every case constant associated with the switch statement must be assignment compatible with the type of the switch statement's Expression (§5.2)." As such, you can't use a constant double or float, but only because you can't use a double or float expression. I should also add, you can't switch on a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the `switch` statement can work with `Integer`.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

The `case` is only working with constant values, e.g. primitives and compile-time String.

Your SAMPLE field that you pass to the `case` statement should be of primitive type.

Comment: Be careful, though: if your Integer value is null in the switch statement, you'll get a NullPointerException.

Comment: that's true of course - just clarifying the details a little bit regarding what's allowed in a switch and a case statement

Comment: @user7294900 read the fist sentence till the end...